# add multiple values per key to a dictionary depending on if statement

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to transform a path into a python dictionary where `parent folder = key` and `folder content = values (e.g 'a/foo' 'a/bar' 'b/root' 'b/data'` needs to be `{ 'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': ['root', 'data']}`) I got my dictionary initialized `d = {'a': [], 'b': [] }`and my list of values `l = ['a/foo', 'a/bar', 'b/root', 'b/data']`

I did a nested for loop with an if statement who takes care of saying which value should be assigned to with key and remove the said key from the value path (e.g 'a/root' becomes 'root')

```
for key in d:
    myIndex = len(key)
    for value in l:
        if value[:myIndex] == key:
            d[key].append(value[myIndex+1:])
```

The thing is that I get the values in the right format exept that I get all of them for each key `{ a: ['foo', 'bar', 'root', 'data'], b: ['foo', 'bar', 'root', 'data'] }` as if my if statement is simply being ignored. If someone has an idea of the problem! Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you are initializing both key entries with a reference to the same empty list

Comment: Works fine with Python3 on my machine ([Imgur](http://imgur.com/a/pKtGW)). Seems your question is different from what you actually did, or your Python has something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the structure of your result, [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can handle this more easily:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

lst = ['a/foo', 'a/bar', 'b/root', 'b/data']

for path in lst:
   k, v = path.split('/')
   d[k].append(v)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': ['root', 'data'], 'a': ['foo', 'bar']})
```

Comment: Might be more generalisable to use `k,v = os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, that could be one generalization for multi-structured paths. Good one!

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to split to folder and subfolder.

```
d = {'a': [], 'b': [] }
l = ['a/foo', 'a/bar', 'b/root', 'b/data']
for key in d:
    for value in l:
        sep = value.split('/')
        if key == sep[0]:
            d[key].append(sep[1])
print(d)
# {'b': ['root', 'data'], 'a': ['foo', 'bar']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with the way you initialize your dictionary **customersDatabases** :

Instead of :

```
customersDatabases = d # problem with keys initialization (pointer to same empty list)
```

Try :

```
customersDatabases = dict(d) # new instance properly initialized
```